# Spigot replaced with ball valve- now the water gets out like from a water cannon...why?

Tags: water, valve

I just replaced an outdoor spigot with a ball valve. Now when I open the valve the water comes out with a huge pressure...do you know why ? When I had the spigot in place that one provided a much smoother water flow.

what could be the reason?

Comment: You could (and probably should) install a hose pressure regulator (aka pressure reducer) on the valve. $7-14 or so. And/or change back to an ordinary hose bibb valve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ball valve offers a straight through path for the water. It's bore hole is highly likely to be smaller than the feed pipe behind it so the bore acts like a hose nozzle.

The older style faucets have a complex path flow for the water through the device which causes turbulence in the flow and also a pressure drop. This is what makes it look to you that the flow is somehow more gentle.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, I did not think about that. So from what you are saying there is no way to open the valve to fill a bucket of water without getting completely soaked right? That means that a hose must be always connected to it....

Comment: Change back to a spigot type valve, the valve styles you should look for are a "bib" style or "globe valve". Both are designed to be throttled.

Comment: I hate the valves that have rubber in them. They suck. Is there any model made without rubber?

Answer (score 1):

Quarter-turn ball-valves are designed to be entirely on or entirely off. The aperture at intermediate positions does not vary linearly with handle position.

There are two major types of ball-valve, standard and full-bore. A full-bore ball-valve is pretty much designed to give you either no-flow or full unrestricted flow.

Ball valves are not intended to give fine control over the rate of flow. They are excellent for isolation, service or shut-off valves.

Normal outdoor taps (spigots) are designed with a multi-turn handle designed to progressively regulate the flow in a way that varies more linearly with the rotation of the handle. The greater number of turns also provides finer control over flow. A quarter turn of such a tap may provide adequate flow for some uses but is probably a small fraction of full aperture.